# Lagrangian Problem: A wedge of mass $M$ having a smooth face and a perfectly rough surface, making with each other an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems

This problem is an example (page 26, ex. 3) from An Introduction to the Use of Generalized Coordinates in Mechanics and Physics by Byerly. The Kinetic Energy and equations of motion are given and I'm to reproduce it.

> A wedge of mass $M$ having a smooth face and a perfectly rough surface, making with each other an angle $\alpha$, is placed with its smooth face on a horizontal table, and a sphere of mass $m$ and radius a is placed on the wedge and rolls down. Find the motion.
>
> $\hspace{0.5cm}$ Let $x$ be the distance the wedge moves on the table, and $y$ the distance the sphere rolls down the plane.
>
> $\hspace{.5cm}$ Note that $\hspace{.3cm} T = \frac{1}{2}[M+m]\dot{x}^2+\frac{m}{2}[\frac{a^2+k^2}{a^2}\dot{y}^2-2\dot{x}\dot{y}\cos \alpha]$
>
> $\hspace{1cm}\textit{Ans.}\hspace{.25cm}(m+M)x-mg\cos\alpha = 0,\hspace{.25cm}\frac{7}{5}y-x\cos\alpha = \frac{1}{2}gt^2\sin\alpha$

What I've done:

Thinking about the Lagrangian, it seems obvious that $\frac{1}{2}[M+m]\dot{x}^2$ is the kinetic energy of the wedge-sphere system generated by the work the sphere does on the wedge due to gravity. With that logic, the second term then must be the kinetic energy of the sphere. Here I attempt a conformal mapping to the moving block system (though I am not sure if that's what I'm $\textit{actually}$ doing since the wedge velocity is not necessarily constant). Anyways, I write

$$x' = x+(s_0-y)\cos\alpha,\hspace{1cm}\delta x' = \delta x-\delta y\cos\alpha$$
$$y' = (s_0-y)\sin\alpha ,\hspace{1cm}\delta y' = -\delta y\sin\alpha $$
$$\dot{x}' = \dot{x}-\dot{y}\cos\alpha,\hspace{1cm}\dot{y}' = -\dot{y}\sin\alpha$$
$$\dot{x}'^2 = \dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\cos^2\alpha -2\dot{x}\dot{y}\cos\alpha,\hspace{1cm}\dot{y}'^2 = \dot{y}^2\sin^2\alpha$$
and putting it all together,

$$T = \frac{1}{2}[M+m]\dot{x}^2+\frac{m}{2}[\dot{x}'^2+\dot{y}'^2]$$
$$T = \frac{1}{2}[M+m]\dot{x}^2+\frac{m}{2}[\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2\cos^2\alpha -2\dot{x}\dot{y}\cos\alpha+\dot{y}^2\sin^2\alpha]$$
$$T = \frac{1}{2}[M+m]\dot{x}^2+\frac{m}{2}[\dot{y}^2+\dot{x}^2-2\dot{x}\dot{y}\cos\alpha]$$

Which appears close but I have a bad feeling about the $\dot{x}^2$ term. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A discussion about this homework-like question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113235/discussion-on-question-by-bransbrain-lagrangian-problem-a-wedge-of-mass-m-hav).